# regex to replace the file name with * and path ,extension should be as it is

Tags: regex, makefile

I have nearly 6000 file names including absolute path, How can I replace only filename with * only not the entire path. looking for a regex to find only filename.

```
$(wildcard C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/dsfsdfs_files/colorschememapping.xml) \
$(wildcard C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/fsdewrwebxd_files/filelist.xml) \
$(wildcard C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/FallingEdgeDelay_files/themedata.thmx) \
$(wildcard C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/test/Fed_XX.xlsx) \
$(wildcard C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/test/Fed_results.mat) \
$(wildcard C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/test/Fed_test.slx) \
```

Result should be

```
$(wildcard C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/dsfsdfs_files/*.xml) \
$(wildcard C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/FallingEdgeDelay_files/*.thmx) \
$(wildcard C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/test/*.xlsx) \
$(wildcard C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/test/*.mat) \
$(wildcard C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/test/*.slx) \
```

Comment: The shell does not know about regular expressions. You don't tell us what shell you're using, so I'm assuming `bash`. The easy way would be to use `$(dirname C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/test/)` ? Or do you want to edit your `Makefile` and change that path? Please [edit] your question and clarify it.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is it about regular expression or make functions? Please provide examples of the input strings and the desired results.

Comment: iam working on windows7 64bit and make is from matlab gmake. i have used dirname ,but it is not rendering all files from sub folders recursively. as i am preparing dependency files for my make rules. the dependent folder has nearly 6000 file with different sub folders and file extensions. hence iam getting into each subfolder and reading all extensions only using wildcard function. i am looking for a reg ex which will replace those filenames with * not the entire path or extensions.

Comment: I have no knowledge of Matlab gmake, but it should be easy enough to convert this regex `(?:[^/]+)\.(\w+\)\s*\\)$` to do a replace `*.$1`

Comment: Thank you verymuch @Theo . I already captured files list using recursive dir command and redirected to a txt file . i want to replace all the file names with * and put it into a variable to make a dependencies list. my problem resolved with your regex " (?:[^\/]+)\. ", here i have just added an escape char before forward slash as(\/). Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely clear as to your question. But you say in a comment:

> I already captured files list using recursive dir command and redirected to a txt file. I want to replace all the file names with * and put it into a variable to make a dependencies list.

From that, it is not too difficult. Suppose your text file is `foo.txt`:

```
C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/dsfsdfs_files/colorschememapping.xml
C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/fsdewrwebxd_files/filelist.xml
C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/FallingEdgeDelay_files/themedata.thmx
C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/test/Fed_XX.xlsx
C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/test/Fed_results.mat
C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/test/Fed_test.slx
```

One could get rid of the filenames in a variey of ways. For example,

```
sed 's_[^/]*\.\([^./]*\)$_*.\1_' foo.txt
```

which gives:

```
C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/dsfsdfs_files/*.xml
C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/fsdewrwebxd_files/*.xml
C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/FallingEdgeDelay_files/*.thmx
C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/test/*.xlsx
C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/test/*.mat
C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/test/*.slx
```

Explanation of regex:

- Search for `something.else` at the *end* of the line, where
- `something` does not contain `/`, and where
- `else` does not contain `/` or a period, and
- then replace it with `*.else`.

You may want to add:

```
| sort | uniq
```

after this to remove any duplicates.

Finally, you can convert this into a form suitable for pasting into your Makefile via:

```
| sed 's/^/$(wildcard /;s/$/) \\/'
```

to get:

```
$(wildcard C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/dsfsdfs_files/*.xml) \
$(wildcard C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/fsdewrwebxd_files/*.xml) \
$(wildcard C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/FallingEdgeDelay_files/*.thmx) \
$(wildcard C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/test/*.xlsx) \
$(wildcard C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/test/*.mat) \
$(wildcard C:/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/test/*.slx) \
```